# In NetSuite using a RESTlet how do you create a new customer record along with it's primary contact record in the relationship tab?

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to create a new customer record with an address record and primary contact record. This code creates the customer record and the address record, but not the primary contact record. Does anyone know how to create the primary contact record?

```
    var customerrecord=nlapiCreateRecord('customer');
    customerrecord.setFieldValue('customform','3'); // form is Customer Form
    customerrecord.setFieldValue('isperson', 'F'); // true or false
    customerrecord.setFieldValue('companyname', datain.companyname);
    customerrecord.setFieldValue('entitystatus', '13');
    customerrecord.setFieldValue('category', '8'); 
    customerrecord.setFieldValue('salesrep', '1606'); // employee record
    customerrecord.setFieldValue('email', datain.email );
    customerrecord.setFieldValue('phone', datain.phone);
    customerrecord.setFieldValue('fax', datain.fax);

    customerrecord.setLineItemValue('addressbook','addressee',1,datain.companyname);
    customerrecord.setLineItemValue('addressbook','attention',1,datain.attention);
    customerrecord.setLineItemValue('addressbook','addr1',1,datain.addr1);
    customerrecord.setLineItemValue('addressbook','addr2',1,datain.addr2);
    customerrecord.setLineItemValue('addressbook','city',1,datain.city);
    customerrecord.setLineItemValue('addressbook','state',1,datain.state);      
    customerrecord.setLineItemValue('addressbook','zip',1,datain.zip);
    customerrecord.setLineItemValue('addressbook','phone',1,datain.phone);
    customerrecord.setLineItemValue('addressbook','label',1,datain.addr1);

    customerrecord.selectNewLineItem('contact');
    customerrecord.setCurrentLineItemValue('contact','contactrole','-10');
    customerrecord.setCurrentLineItemValue('contact','firstname',datain.attention);
    customerrecord.setCurrentLineItemValue('contact','email',datain.email);
    customerrecord.setCurrentLineItemValue('contact','phone',datain.phone);
    customerrecord.commitLineItem('contact');

    var customerid = nlapiSubmitRecord(customerrecord, false, true);

    return "customer record created: " + datain.companyname;
```

Comment: That's about how I've done it using 1.0, in the past.  Though, for the contact, I always create a contact record, and set the company and contactrole on that contact.

Comment: W3BGUY - Thanks for the hint. I changed it to create the contact record after I submit the customerrecord and put the customerid in the company field and it worked. Yeah

  var contactrecord=nlapiCreateRecord('contact');
  contactrecord.setFieldValue('firstname',datain.attention);
  contactrecord.setFieldValue('email',datain.email);
  contactrecord.setFieldValue('phone',datain.phone);
  contactrecord.setFieldValue('company', customerid);
  contactrecord.setFieldValue('contactrole','-10');
  var contactid = nlapiSubmitRecord(contactrecord,false,true);

Comment: Awesome!  Glad to hear it's working for you.